# Custom field updating in database but not showing in UI

Tags: trigger, case, custom-field, update, ui

I have a custom field on the Case object, which is of type Number(18,0).
This field is originally null, but after a trigger call, it gets updated to a certain value fetched from an API.

I have confirmed that the API and the field update are working correctly. A SOQL query will show that the custom field has the correct value after update.

However, on the UI itself, the field always shows up as blank. If I try to edit the field from the UI, it shows the correct field value, but on the Case UI itself (like when viewing the case) the field always shows up as empty.

I have no idea why it's happening. It's clearly assigning the correct value, it's just not showing it in the UI. Any help?

Also, whenever I refresh the page when viewing the case, I get a `COMPONENT ERROR message  [invalid currency code in NumberFormat(): ]`

I have 100% positive unit test coverage. So I'm pretty sure it's not my apex code.

Comment: Can you confirm if the field type is Number(18,0) and not Currency(18,0). The error you specified can occure for Currency fields if there is a mismatch of currency code and the applicable currency format.

Comment: Yeah, it's Number(18, 0)  (Unique) type

Comment: Are you sure the field on the layout is the same as the field you're updating?  There could be two fields with identical labels but different API names.  Does the field appear correctly on reports?

Comment: I am sure, I'm checking the API names, it's the correct name. Besides, like I said, when you try to edit the record through UI, it shows the correct value.

Comment: Can you enable history for that field on case object, and try seeing the history after the update, it may be updating from some other peice of code which may be running after your code does, also check the dependency of the field if its used in other places.

Comment: @sumitbhatt nothing. When inspecting the object through the Edit menu, it shows the correct ID. Also, my callout only occurs when the Case custom resource ID is null, and the callout is only happening once, so I know for a fact that the Case is indeed storing the ID, it's just not showing it in UI. I still get the same error about currencycode, but there's no currency field present.